# How do I use my local MongoDB in a Meteor Developing project?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have spend days looking for answer to this relativ simple question. There are hundreds of questions like this and thousands of answers - but no one straigth and adequite. This tells me that the question may be rather "hot" and the answers maybe not that "hot".
I'm on a Windows environment, and for several reasons I want to be able to connect the projects I'm developing in Meteor to a local mongoDb, maybe an existing db - not the buildin one. Consequently  I've 2 questions:

> **1**.How du I use the local Mongo instead of the buildin on - adhoc, in developing a Meteor project ?
>
> **2**. How do I set up a Meteor project to permanent use a speficic db on the local Mongo, also in developing state.>

After my desert journey with hard to understand and 'informed' answers and desperate solutions -like changing the local - adding scripts to json and adding Mongo_URL in terminal , please tell me what to write and where to write it.
Thanks

Comment: Hi - found a solution myself. Adding the env,var. inside the server:
Meteor.startup(function() { 
 process.env.MONGO_URL='mongodb://localhost:27017/databasename'});  actually worked. But Mongo is a grumphy master - so double quot. is necessary.
Thank you all for your effort and help
and to Derrick: your suggestion is not for Windows

Answer (score 1):

Below you will find the command for setting the MONGO_URL environment variable and running meteor at the same time. If you are unfamiliar with what environment variables are I would do a bit of searching on google so you understand what they are. You will need to update the databasename and port to match your local mongodb.

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/databasename meteor run
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  but you see - this is where the frustrations starts. There are hundreds of answers exactly like your - even the Meteor Docs say so - but it wont work. 
When I write the connection-string in the terminal  - it respond 'MONGO_URL' is not recognized as an internal or external command - if I try to run it in quotationsmarks it says wrong syntax.
If I try to write it inside the server: 
 Meteor.startup(() => {process.env.MONGO_URL='mongodb://localhost:27017/databasename'});  nothing happends ( the db is present - I've used it with MongoDb Compass ).
Please help

Comment: Try setting the environment variable in windows and then leaving it out of the command line. Here is a link with instructions for windows 10.

https://www.architectryan.com/2018/08/31/how-to-change-environment-variables-on-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

If you use npm, define “startLocal” in the scripts section of your package.json, e. g.

```
"startLocal": "ROOT_URL=http://localhost:3000 MAIL_URL=… MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/databasename meteor run --port 3000 --settings settings.json"
```

Then run it using:

```
npm run startLocal
```